# How to install library in npmjs without dependencies?

Tags: npm, npmjs

I use npm.
When I install a library with the following command:

```
npm install select2 --save
```

or

```
npm install https://github.com/select2/select2.git --save
```

all its dependencies are also installed.

How to install the library only(without dependencies)?